Why is my React Native app's state being cleared when switching between apps on iOS, but persists when the app is completely closed and reopened?
This issue developed after upgrading to the latest architecture.
Also, only some parts are getting cleared, such as loggedInUser and homepage lists.
Environment and Setup:

Device:
iPhone 16 Pro, iOS 18.1 Simulator and in Actual Testflight

React Native Version:
0.76.3 with New Architecture Enabled

Other Relevant Libraries:
mobx: "^6.13.5",
mobx-react: "^9.1.1",
react-navigation: 7.x.x



Fixed MobX Store Initialisation Logic
[OLD CODE]
let store: RootStore;

// create the context
const StoreContext = createContext<RootStore | undefined>(undefined);

// create the provider component
export function RootStoreProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  //only create the store once ( store is a singleton)
  const root = store ?? new RootStore();

  return <StoreContext.Provider value={root}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>;
}

[NEW CODE]
// Singleton store variable
let store: RootStore | undefined;

// Create the context
const StoreContext = createContext<RootStore | undefined>(undefined);

// RootStoreProvider Component
export function RootStoreProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  // Initialize the store only once
  if (!store) {
    store = new RootStore();
  }

  return <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>;
}


